# PHP: Replace DOMElement with DOMText node

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I want to create some customised tags for translating, for instance

`<trad>SOMETHING</trad>`

I've also got a file with some $GLOBALS variable, like:

```
$GLOBALS['SOMETHING'] = 'Some text';
```

`$GLOBALS['SOMETHINGELSE'] = 'Some other text';`

So I've been able to show my translation in this way:

```
$string = "<trad>SOMETHING</trad>";

$string = preg_replace('/<trad[^>]*?>([\\s\\S]*?)<\/trad>/','\\1', $string);
echo $GLOBALS[$string];
```

This works perfectly, but when I've got something more complex like the following code, or when I have more occurences of this tag, I'm not able to let it work:

`$string = "Lorem ipsum <trad>SOMETHING</trad> <h1>Hello</h1> <trad>SOMETHINGELSE</trad>";`

I ideally want to create a new variale $string, replacing the values that I found into my  tags and being able to show it with a simple echo.

So I want an output like this with:

`echo $string;
//output: Lorem ipsum Some text <h1>Hello</h1> Some other text`

Can you guys help me?

Comment: You need to use the `DOMDocument` class and its methods (find a tutorial/read PHP manual). Regex isn't the right way to do that. *(You have a structured string = use the structure)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Regex` is not a valid approach for treating `HTMLstring`. Here we are using `DOMDocument` instead of `Regex` to achieve desired output. The last step of `strip_tags` has been done to achieve desired output, there will no need in case a valid HTML string is supplied to `loadHTML`, in that case `saveHTML($node)` will do the job.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/806680)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$array["SOMETHING"]="some text";
$array["SOMETHINGELSE"]="some text other";

$string = "Lorem ipsum <trad>SOMETHING</trad> <h1>Hello</h1> <trad>SOMETHINGELSE</trad>";

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$results=$domDocument->getElementsByTagName("trad");
do
{
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $result->parentNode->replaceChild($domDocument->createTextNode($array[trim($result->nodeValue)]),$result);
    }
}
while($results->length>0);

echo strip_tags($domDocument->saveHTML(),"<h1>");
```

Comment: but in this way I have to predict with the last instruction all the tags that could be inserted? like h1,h2,h3,a, img, etc..?

Comment: @Ame No issues, dont rely on `strip_tags($domDocument->saveHTML(),"<h1>");` but just make sure if you dont apply this then output is surrounded by `p` tag which you can trim, in case when you are not supplying a valid HTML, else it will work fine, You can check it

Comment: @Ame You will get the output like this `<p>Lorem ipsum Some text <h1>Hello</h1> Some other text</p>`, which you can trim.

Comment: ok thank you. Is the array approach the only one available? I can't use my GLOBALS variable right?

Comment: I'm saying  this because I tried to replace $array with $GLOBALS and it doesn't seem to work... if it's easy to solve can you help me? I would be really grateful :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145353/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-ame).